# How to increase each successive image in a for loop by 5 pixels

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I wrote a script in a section of my HTML code to output an image to my browser 10 times by using a for loop. This works fine, but I also want to write a script in the head element of the markup where I can maybe use a function to first create an HTMLCollection from the image elements, and then loop through all ten images in the collection, adding 5 pixels to the width and height properties of each succeeding image element from left to right when any one of the ten images is clicked.

I've tried to research information on HTMLCollections combined with DOM related properties and other equations, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Script from the body element

```
<section>

    <h2>Growing Pumpkins</h2>

    <p id="smashingPumpkins" onclick="growingPumpkins(this)" ></p>      

    <script>           

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                

            document.getElementById("smashingPumpkins").innerHTML += "<img src='bandit.png' />";              

        }

    </script>

</section>
```

Script from the head element:

```
<script>        

    function growingPumpkins(img) {

        var img = document.images;

        for (index in img) {                

            document.getElementById("smashingPumpkins").innerHTML = img[index].style.width + 1.05;
            document.getElementById("smashingPumpkins").innerHTML = img[index].style.height + 1.05;
        }
    }        

</script>
```

The size of each image should increase by 5 pixels spanning from left to right (apologies for the redundancy) when output to the browser. However, I have been unable to accomplish this, and only see the number 1.05 when I click on one of the images.

Comment: Multiply 5px by `index`?

Comment: Where would I do this inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                

  document.getElementById("smashingPumpkins").innerHTML += 
    `<img src='bandit.png' style="width:${base + i*5}px; height:${base + i*5}px   "/>`;              

}
```

Of course the 'base' being used in the style attribute is something you set, like 100 or however many pixels you want the height and width of the first one to be

**EDIT:**
That was just to make each picture bigger than the last, which is not exactly what you asked.  But your comment makes me think I should leave it for learning purposes.  What you could do have each picture expand on click, and each one expand 10px bigger than the one before it, is this:

Add a class to your images to easy targeting, then target them into an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                
  document.getElementById("smashingPumpkins").innerHTML +=
    "<img src='bandit.png' class="expandingImg" />";              
}

var images = document.querySelectorAll('.expandingImg') // creates an array of your image elements
```

Now loop through your array of elements and attach an event listener to each one.  The event listener will change the style element of that element, based on the element's position in the array.  So elements later in the array will expand more than ones earlier in the array.  This also eliminates the need for your `onclick="growingPumpkins(this)"` because the eventlisteners are being added in this immediately invoked functional expression (IIFE):

```
(function growingPumpkins() {
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {                
     images.addEventListener('click', function(){
       images[i].style = `style="width:${base + i*5}px; height:${base + i*5}px`
     }, false)
})()
```

I think that should do it.  You'll need to add *another* event listener so that they shrink back down to their original size, like `mouseleave` or something like that.  Hopefully this works and is helpful.

Comment: It is working, but the images from the pre-clicked loop are still there also.How can I remove them/

Comment: oops my answer was just how to make each image 10px bigger than the last, nothing to do with clicking on it.  let me edit my answer